# SetInterval not working properly in ReactJS and Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout, setinterval

so I have a react modal which has a countdown timer. The timer doesn't seem to work on Chrome but works on Firefox. On Chrome timer starts to count down but decreases its ticking pase when it ticks for about 20 seconds.

This is the current implementation of the modal and the timer.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import BaseModal from './Index';

export default function OtpModal(props: Props) {
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState<number>(120);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('tick', timeLeft);
      setTimeLeft(timeLeft - 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [timeLeft]);

  return (
    <BaseModal>
      <div>
        OTP timeout in{' '}
        <span style={{fontWeight: '500'}}>
          {Math.floor(timeLeft / 60)}:
          {(timeLeft % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0')} 
        </span>
      </div>
    </BaseModal>
  )
}
```

Comment: I've checked this problem, but it had no problems. Perhaps another part of your application has affected this section? Is that possible?

Comment: I am unable to verify this for now. The fact that it works fine on Firefox makes me rethink this.

Answer (score 1):

You are running your useEffect and setting a new timer at each second.

Maybe it is causing issue if there is timer throttling.

You can set only one timer and run once your useEffect like that:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setTimeLeft((prev) => (prev > 0 ? prev - 1 : 0));
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I think Chrome does some throttling for optimization

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to create a hook called `useTimer` to handle counting down the time. That way, each `<Timer>` only needs to know the time it will render.

```js
const { useCallback, useEffect, useState } = React;

const useTimer = ({ seconds, refreshRate = 50 }) => {
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(seconds);
  const [intervalId, setIntervalId] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const endTime = Date.now() + (seconds * 1e3);
    setIntervalId((currentIntervalId) => {
      if (currentIntervalId) {
        clearInterval(currentIntervalId);
      }
      const internalIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
        const diff = Math.floor((endTime - Date.now()) / 1e3);
        setTimeLeft(diff);
        if (diff < 1) {
          clearInterval(internalIntervalId);
        }
      }, refreshRate)
      return internalIntervalId;
    });
  }, [seconds, refreshRate]);
  
  const cancel = useCallback(() => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [intervalId]);
  
  return { timeLeft, cancel };
}

const Timer = ({ seconds }) => {
  const { timeLeft, cancel } = useTimer({ seconds });
  
  // Cancel all timers after 30 seconds...
  useEffect(() => {
    if (cancel) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        cancel();
      }, 3e4); /* 30 seconds */
    }
  }, [cancel]);

  return (
    <div>
      {Math.floor(timeLeft / 60)}:
      {(timeLeft % 60).toString().padStart(2, '0')} 
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Timer seconds={120} />
      <Timer seconds={60} />
      <Timer seconds={30} />
      <Timer seconds={10} />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

When we run `clearInterval` and `setInterval`, their timing shifts. If we re-render and re-apply effects too often, the interval never gets a chance to fire!

I would recommend studying [this blog post](https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/) about problems with the `setInterval` and react hooks. The blog post suggests creating a custom hook(`useInterval`) as follows:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}
```

**Usage**

```js
  useInterval(() => {
    setTimeLeft((prev) => (prev > 0 ? prev - 1 : 0));
  }, delay);
```

Comment: It works on Firefox but not on Chrome. I am confused right now.

Comment: What is your chrome version?

Comment: 117.0.5938.149(official Build) (64 bit)

Comment: @labs I don't think I can help you anymore with the information provided if you want, you can share your code for me to take a look at it.

Comment: okay. The frontend is served from the backend , and I am suspecting it could be a problem.